# Must specify "tsConfigPath" in the configuration of @ngtools/webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have upgraded my webpack `"@types/webpack": "^3.0.13"` to `"@types/webpack": "^3.8.5"` and `"ngc-webpack": "~3.2.2"` to `"ngc-webpack": "~4.1.1"`.

When I start the project it returns

```
Error: Must specify "tsConfigPath" in the configuration of @ngtools/webpack.
```

Even though, I have added the path according to [@ngtolls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack)

Here is my `package.json` details

```
Angular: 4.4.4
"webpack": "^3.10.1",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.10.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^2.0.4",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1",
"webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"webpack-merge": "~4.1.1"
```

`webpack.dev.js`

```
/**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */

const helpers = require("./helpers");
const webpackMerge = require("webpack-merge"); // used to merge webpack configs
// const webpackMergeDll = webpackMerge.strategy({plugins: 'replace'});
const commonConfig = require("./webpack.common.js"); // the settings that are common to prod and dev

/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
const AddAssetHtmlPlugin = require("add-asset-html-webpack-plugin");
const DefinePlugin = require("webpack/lib/DefinePlugin");
const NamedModulesPlugin = require("webpack/lib/NamedModulesPlugin");
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require("webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin");

const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;

/**
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const ENV = (process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = "development");
const HOST = process.env.HOST || "localhost";
const PORT = 4200;
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag("hot");
const METADATA = webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }).metadata, {
  host: HOST,
  port: PORT,
  ENV: ENV,
  HMR: HMR
});

var dotEnv = require("dotenv");
dotEnv.load({ path: require('path').resolve('/.env') });


module.exports = function(options) {
  return webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {

    devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",


    output: {

      path: helpers.root("dist"),


      filename: "[name].bundle.js",


      sourceMapFilename: "[file].map",


      chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js",

      library: "ac_[name]",
      libraryTarget: "var"
    },

    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
        },

        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
          include: [helpers.root("src", "styles")]
        },

        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
          include: [helpers.root("src", "styles")]
        }
      ]
    },

    plugins: [
      new AotPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: 'src/tsconfig.json',
        entryModule: 'src/app/app.module#AppModule',
        sourceMap: true
      }),

      new DefinePlugin({
        ENV: JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        HMR: METADATA.HMR,
        "process.env": {
          ENV: JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
          HMR: METADATA.HMR
        }
      }),


      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        debug: true,
        options: {}
      })
    ],

    devServer: {
      port: METADATA.port,
      host: METADATA.host,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      watchOptions: {
        // if you're using Docker you may need this
        // aggregateTimeout: 300,
        // poll: 1000,
        ignored: /node_modules/
      },
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },

      setup: function(app) {
        // For example, to define custom handlers for some paths:
        // app.get('/some/path', function(req, res) {
        //   res.json({ custom: 'response' });
        // });
      },
      proxy: {
        "/api/v1": {
          target: "http://localhost:3000"
        },

      }
    },


    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: "empty",
      process: true,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false,
      fs: 'empty'
    },
    externals: [
      {
        './cptable': 'var cptable'
      }
    ]
  });
};
```

I have searched a lot, but I could not find any useful answer. the question sound is silly I know, but I don't know how to solve it.

can someone please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error while following a [tutorial from AngularInDepth](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135).

I changed this code in webpack.config.js:

```
new AotPlugin({
  "mainPath": "main.ts",
  "entryModule": "app/app.module#AppModule"
})
```

to:

```
new AotPlugin({
    "tsConfigPath": "tsconfig.json",
    "mainPath": "main.ts",
    "entryModule": "app/app.module#AppModule",
  })
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well.

First, I followed the error logs. I noticed that the object received as "options" was

`{ 
    disabled: false, 
    tsConfig: 'blahblah/app/tsconfig.json' 
}`.

I went into the webpack.common.js (also labelled as webpack.js depending on your project setup) and added the tsConfigPath.

1. Go in the exported module, in the plugins array, and
2. find either new AotPlugin, new AngularCompilerPlugin, or new ngcWebpack.NgcWebpackPlugin
3. add the tsConfigPath. And probably don't erase the original.